# Is there a linux distro, that is not installed, but runs from the browser?

Tags: command-line, distribution-choice

I remember hearing about something similar.

My constraints are:

- It may not be installed on the machine
- It may not be booted via USB or LiveCD

What I need, in **decreasing** order of priority:
0. free
1. gcc, binutils, bash
2. low network traffic e.g. =< 1kbps
3. sufficient resources to cross-compile gcc
4. ability to install programs from repos

Comment: That isn't really a Linux distro, that's remotely accessing a Linux machine via (probably) a Java applet in your browser. Probably running VNC.

Comment: That would be an option, as would be something like MinGW (but MinGBrowser :D)

Comment: If you want linux running in the browser, check out the [JavaScript qemu port](http://www.bellard.org/jslinux/). But I doubt that you have enough resources to cross compile.

Comment: There is no such thing as Linux running in your browser. You might have a VNC applet, or a ssh applet, etc. running in your browser. But it's definitely accessing a remote machine (or VM) running Linux.

Comment: @Marco wow, that's... damn, impressive. But yeah, I wouldn't want to try to run gcc in that. 13M of memory! It does have a hello.c to compile, takes a good while. And that's not with gcc...

Comment: Sounds like you want to SSH into a Linux box somewhere. There are SSH clients that run in your browser.

Comment: @Marco BTW, it took about 15 minutes for `gcc -O3 hello.c -o hello` to finish, on my quite fast i7 (Firefox 19).

Comment: @derobert Spot on! First step occomplished. Second step is building the kernel :P

Comment: @Marco, I think you got right 0), 1) and 2). Not bad!

Comment: @Marco, derobert chrome running on i5-2520M at 2.5GHz did compile hello.c in 5 minutes. However, I believe that Fabrice Bellard cross compiled the kernel on some more suitable platform :)

Comment: @Marco JavaScript qemu port? That's worse than http://jsmachines.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why you have such unusual constraints. No
installation, no live CD and low network traffic excludes the obvious
solutions like booting a distro from USB, setting up a VM or using a remote
system via SSH.

How do you actually plan to run such a system? If you really only have a
browser check out the [JavaScript qemu port](http://www.bellard.org/jslinux/).
But I doubt that you have enough resources to cross compile applications or
that you will be able to use such a system efficiently.

> 1. free

Most of the linux distributions are free.

> 1. gcc, binutils, bash

Most of the distributions ship with those apps either pre-installed or
installable via packet manager or from source.

> 1. low network traffic e.g. =< 1kbps

Linux distributions don't generate network traffic. It's the applications that
generate the traffic. But the problem here probably is that I don't understand
what you want to do.

> 1. sufficient resources to cross-compile gcc

That's the crucial point here. The JavaScript solution does not provide
sufficient resources and you are not allowed to install a distribution
locally.

> 1. ability to install programs from repos

Possible with most of the available distributions.

Depending on what you actually want to do, I guess the best way is to set up a
remote server and using an SSH solution which allows access from a browser
(e.g. via Java applet). The network traffic is low and you don't need to
install additional software.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion and answer, Marco. The purpose of the question is to be able to test some gcc behavior on my work Windows7 machine. However I lack sufficient arguments to ask if I could install MinGW. I guess I'll just wait for an excuse ;P

Comment: By its GPL license, Linux (the kernel) is free, the pieces making up typical Linux distributions are also GPL or other open source licences. So _all_ distributions are free. They might include non-free pieces, though.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an appliance with `susestudio`  and include any tools from opensuse's repos(external repos or uploaded packages). After creating a appliance you can run it from susestudio's `Testdrive`(vnc'ing into an VM). That would solve everything besides #3. The VM is only given 512mb RAM/512 swap and the testdrive session only last for an hour(to prevent people was wasting their resources.)

Comment: But like others said, your constraints are hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You cold get a cheap machine to do your experiments on, or even use [Amazon's EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) or some similar service.